# Making sense of Inception V3 layers

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

The last layers of the Inception V3 network include a 8x8x2048 "mixed10" layer followed by a 1x1x2048 "avg_pool" layer. What is the real difference between these two layers ie. does the "mixed10" layer capture all the features of an image for example or is that only accomplished in the "avg_pool" layer?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, the avg_pool layer is obtained by, for each of the 2048 feature maps in mixed10, taking the global average (over the 64 values in the 8x8 feature map). Depending on your application, it can make sense to use either - if you want to use the network for classification and use the network as a feature extractor, using the average-pooled version and training a classifier on top makes sense.

Comment: That was my understanding but using the mixed10 as the feature extractor layer gave very poor results than the avg_pool layer. Hence, my question. From my experiments, it appears the two layers cannot be considered equivalent even though they capture all feature information.

Comment: I didn't say they are equivalent. I said, depending on the application, it can be better to use one or the other.

Comment: Sure. What is the criteria to use mixed10 over avg_pool?